# Magento2 Plugins not working - before/after

Tags: magento2, plugin

I have no issues when doing an around plugin - but for a before and after plugin, I always get errors:

For instance, I want to print out something before or after a REST call is made:

```
class Rest
{

 /**
  * Handle REST request
  *
  * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface|\Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request $request
  */
   public function beforeDispatch(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
   {
       var_dump($request->getContent());
   }

}

<type name="Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest">
    <plugin name="restPlugin" type="MyCompany\MyMod\Plugin\Rest" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

I get the following.

'Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to MyCompany\MyMod\Plugin\Rest::beforeDispatch() must implement interface Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface, instance of Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor given

It's the same if I do after - I've tried to cast the input variable differently, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You class should be

```
class Rest
{
    /**
     * Handle REST request
     *
     * @param \Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest $subject
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface|\Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request $request
     */
    public function beforeDispatch(
        \Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        error_log('Inside Rest');
    }
}
```

Clear cache and delete var/generation/*